# Can I put this in separate class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I have this repetitive piece of code:

```
var expCodes = (from cpdet in _dataContextOrders.CodeProfileDetails
                join cpd in _dataContextOrders.CodeProfileDefinitions on cpdet.CodeProfileDefinitionID equals cpd.ID
                join cp in _dataContextOrders.CodeProfiles on cpd.CodeProfileID equals cp.ID
                join cc in _dataContextOrders.FMSCostCentres on cpdet.CostCentreID equals cc.ID
                join ec in _dataContextOrders.FMSExpenseCodes on cpdet.ExpenseCodeID equals ec.ID
                where cp.ID == Convert.ToInt32(intCostCodeProfileId)
                                  && cpdet.CostCentreID == Convert.ToInt32(intCostCentreSelected)
                                  && ec.Active == true
                select new
                {
                    ec.ID,
                    ec.CostCentreID,
                    ExpenseCodeExternalRef = ec.ExternalRef,
                    ExpenseCodeDescription = ec.Description,
                    displayExpenseCode = ec.ExternalRef + " " + ec.Description
                 }).Distinct().OrderBy(ec => ec.displayExpenseCode);

ddlExpCode1.DataSource = expCodes;
ddlExpCode1.DataTextField = "displayExpenseCode";
ddlExpCode1.DataValueField = "ID";
```

What I would like to do is to put it into a Class on its own, as we did before LinqToSql, that I can call from my aspx.cs page, using the 2 parameters, intCostCodeProfileId and intCostCodeProfileId and it will return the data for the Drop Down List.

How can I do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a normal class (e.g. Connection.cs) and add some code like this:

```
public class MyDataSourceReturner
{
    public static Object retDatasource(Object _dataContextOrders, int intCostCodeProfileId){
    var expCodes = (from cpdet in _dataContextOrders.CodeProfileDetails
            join cpd in _dataContextOrders.CodeProfileDefinitions on cpdet.CodeProfileDefinitionID equals cpd.ID
            join cp in _dataContextOrders.CodeProfiles on cpd.CodeProfileID equals cp.ID
            join cc in _dataContextOrders.FMSCostCentres on cpdet.CostCentreID equals cc.ID
            join ec in _dataContextOrders.FMSExpenseCodes on cpdet.ExpenseCodeID equals ec.ID
            where cp.ID == Convert.ToInt32(intCostCodeProfileId)
                              && cpdet.CostCentreID == Convert.ToInt32(intCostCentreSelected)
                              && ec.Active == true
            select new
            {
                ec.ID,
                ec.CostCentreID,
                ExpenseCodeExternalRef = ec.ExternalRef,
                ExpenseCodeDescription = ec.Description,
                displayExpenseCode = ec.ExternalRef + " " + ec.Description
             }).Distinct().OrderBy(ec => ec.displayExpenseCode);

    return expCodes;
    }
}
```

Afterwards you can use this code like this:

```
ddlExpCode1.DataSource = MyDataSourceReturner.retDatasource(_dataContextOrders, 5);
```

and receive your DataSource.

Comment: Brilliant. That is just the solution I am looking for.

Comment: You're welcome :)
I forgot to add the intCostCentreSelected-parameter, but you surely know how to add a third parameter to the function.

Comment: I have another instance with some extra modifies later on that do not work if I move it away:

Comment: You can add those modifiers as parameters, so you have the 'context' right with you, like i did with "Object _dataContextOrders" in the parameters.

Comment: -1, It will not really be useful to return an anonymous object inside an `object` type. The caller can't access any properties returned and can't cast it to a type.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a model class that matches the properties in your `select` statement (ID, CostCentreId etc.). Then modify the `select new {` to `select new FreshlyCreatedModelClass() {`.

The only way to return an anonymous type from your method is to use either `IEnumerable<object>` or `IEnumerable<dynamic>` neither which should be recommended in this scenario. Your method should return `IEnumerable<FreshlyCreatedModelClass>` (or `IQueryable<FreshlyCreatedModelClass>` could be used if you need to build the query further).

After you have sorted the model class, you can simply move the code to a separate method.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand this at all.

Comment: @SteveStaple What about it don't you understand?  Create a new class to represent the objects returned instead of using an anonymous type.  Create a sequence of those new types, not anonymous objects.  Basically give the anonymous objects a name.