# Query on using a class with LinqToSql

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I want to put the following code in a class by itself so that I can reuse it:

```
     var activePersons = (from p in _dataContextOrders.Persons
                             select new
                             {
                                 p.ID,
                                 p.WindowsUserID,
                                 p.Name,
                                 p.CommonShortName,
                                 p.TeamID,
                                 p.Telephone,
                                 p.Fax,
                                 p.Email,
                                 p.FMSBudgetOfficerID,
                                 p.Active
                             }).Where(p => p.Active).OrderBy(p => p.CommonShortName);
```

So I can return the Object activePersons. I would replace all this with this:

```
    var activePersons = DataAccessLayer.ActivePersons.GetActivePersons();
```

But further down the page, I have this:

```
    var currentUser = activePersons.SingleOrDefault(p => p.WindowsUserID == strWindowsSessionUserId);
```

This now returns a compile error. Is there a way round this?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: You accepted the wrong answer to [your earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21630745/1159478).  Had you used the appropriate answer to that question you wouldn't be in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting the error is because of the anonymous object you are selecting in your query with `new` keyword. You can't return anonymous object from your method , so I guess you are returning `object`. Now for your method caller it is an `object` type object and it doesn't exposes all the properties selected in the query, *(and you can't cast it to a type since you don't know the type)* Hence the error.

You **need to create a new class** and with all the properties and return `IEnumerable<yourClass>` from the method.

There is a [way to return anonymous object mentioned by Jon Skeet](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/01/09/horrible-grotty-hack-returning-an-anonymous-type-instance.aspx) but he doesn't recommend it.

Define a class like:

```
class ReturnedObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string WindowsUserID { get; set; }
    //..... rest of the properties
}
```

and then in your query:

```
 var activePersons = (from p in _dataContextOrders.Persons
         select new ReturnedObject
         {
             ID = p.ID,
             WindowsUserID = p.WindowsUserID,
             //rest of the properties
```

in your method specify return type as:

```
public IEnumerable<ReturnedObject> GetActivePersons(//parameters
```

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I got that working in the end. DRY programming for all!!

Comment: @SteveStaple, you are welcome, but you accepted the [wrong answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21631133/961113) on your earlier question for the similar topic.